# Wifi became KO on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: networking, apt, wireless, upgrade, 18.10

My WiFi stopped working after apt upgrade. No WiFi section appears in the network properties panel.

Here is the result of `sudo lspci -v` for my WiFi:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    I/O ports at c000 [disabled] [size=256]
    Memory at ef100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-b8-22-01
    Capabilities: [158] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel modules: r8822be
```

Here is the response to sudo modprobe r8822be

```
[sudo] Mot de passe de romain : 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8822be': Operation not permitted
```

Here is the result of grep -r r8822be /lib/modules

```
Fichier binaire /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko correspondant
Fichier binaire /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.dep.bin correspondant
Fichier binaire /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.symbols.bin correspondant
/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.order:kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko
/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.symbols:alias symbol:rtl_halmac_get_ops_pointer r8822be
/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.symbols:alias symbol:rtl_phydm_get_ops_pointer r8822be
/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.dep:kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko: kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.alias:alias pci:v000010ECd0000B822sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8822be
Fichier binaire /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.alias.bin correspondant
Fichier binaire /lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko correspondant
Fichier binaire /lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/modules.dep.bin correspondant
Fichier binaire /lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/modules.symbols.bin correspondant
/lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/modules.order:kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko
/lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/modules.symbols:alias symbol:rtl_halmac_get_ops_pointer r8822be
/lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/modules.symbols:alias symbol:rtl_phydm_get_ops_pointer r8822be
/lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/modules.dep:kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko: kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
/lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/modules.alias:alias pci:v000010ECd0000B822sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8822be
Fichier binaire /lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/modules.alias.bin correspondant
```

Any idea how I can get my WiFi card back running?

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8822be` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: romain@romain-X705UDR:~$ sudo modprobe r8822be
[sudo] Mot de passe de romain : 1
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8822be': Operation not permitted

Comment: I strongly feel that this is the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806472 "The r8822be module alias is intact, trying to modprobe it or insert results in a "operation not permitted" error. " Please disable Secure Boot.

Comment: I put the result in my question, too long for comment

Comment: Yes chili555, disabling Secure Boot works fine, but it used to work with Secure Boot enabled before my upgrade. I hope this bug will be fixed. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As said chili555 the bug is reported here:
 bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806472

Disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS is the workaround while waiting for real bug fix.